# UWP set map icon to not moving when zooming

Tags: c#, maps, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

How to set Map Icon to be not moving when zooming and also directly point to precise location? Because from what I see when the map zooming out, it doesn't point to latitude and longitude I set. But when I zooming in it show to the correct latitude and longitude.

Here is some code I try

```
 var originPoint =
                        new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
                        {
                            Latitude = -7.9301346197875446,
                            Longitude = 112.63243081568352
                        });
                    //create POI
                    var originPin = new MapIcon
                    {
                        Location = originPoint,
                        NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
                        ZIndex = 0,
                        Image =
                            RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(
                                new Uri(
                                    "ms-appx:///mapicon.png"))
                    };
                    nativeMap.MapElements.Add(originPin);
```

According to [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn637082) I need to set normalized anchor point. But what is the correct point to set? I already try (0,0),(0.5,1),(0.5,0.5)(1,1) and it still need to be zooming in to show the correct position. Look at my image below

[image: Zooming out]
[image: Zooming in]

Answer (score 1):

The NormalizedAnchorPoint is the correct item to use in this case... it is a point system with 0,0 being upper left corner. And 1,1 being lower right corner.

Seeing your image, we assume your anchor point is the lower left corner... ( the red dot ) so try (1,0) or (0,1) ( I'm not sure at the top of my head what the x axis is, I would think the first point )